# Are forms necessary for Django authentication?

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, forms-authentication

I'm new to Django and I'm working on a project which will be using APIs with Django REST framework.
And working on it, creating the authentication using [DjangoDoc AUTH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/), I was wondering if it was necessary to use these forms, are there any other authentication or validation methods?

I took a look at these articles:

- [DjangoDoc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/forms/)
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-Django-forms)
- [Django
  Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms)

But I can't see if they're really necessary or if there is another way.

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own validations in your views, but it makes your code lengthy and you may omit some of the key validations required for authentication. 
If you want, to have custom validations for the default forms you can use clean_methods to have your custom validations

Comment: And if I'm using a Front-End framework, like React, what is the use of Django's forms? Does it at any point validate data received by HTTP request?
Or will the Front-End form do it?

Comment: Doing Front-end validations is not a good idea in few ways , its always better to have a validations from backend, we can use django forms for frontend frameworks also, but you need to discuss with the django developer for the fields he used in the form

Comment: Why use Django forms when in the serializers you can use for exemple `foobar = Foobar.objects.create(**validated_data)`? Because this already checks and validates the data sent by a new request